# I want to upload image in different directory on same server in php

Tags: php, image, ionic-framework, ionic4, image-upload

My API is in the `'deals-app/image_upload.php'` аnd I want to save upload my image on `'direct_discount/assets/images/offer_images/'`. Both directories are on same server:

Here is my code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
   if (isset($_FILES['files']['name'])) {
    $errors = [];
    $path = 'image_upload/  ';
    $extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif','doc','pdf'];
    $file_name = array();  
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++){
    $all_files = count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);  
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
        $file_dataname = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
        $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['files']['name'][$i])));
        // $file_imagename = uniqid().".".$file_ext;
        $file_imagename = $file_dataname ; 
        $file_name[] = $file_imagename;
        $file = $path . $file_imagename;
        if (empty($errors)) {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file);
        }
    }
```

I want to upload multiple images in this directory: `direct_discount/assets/images/offer_images/`. I gave this path in my path variable but it doesn't work. How can I solve it?

Comment: is `direct_discount/assets/images/offer_images/` a sub-folder for where the PHP code is running?

Answer (score 0):

$path = '/var/www/html/{folder to store images}'; // (replace with path to localhost folder /var/www/html/)